# Is there other way to get the area between 2 lines using other than iteration? (segmentation of medical image)

Tags: python

I made segmented image comprised of 2 lines from medical photo.
I want to get the average thickness or area between 2 lines. 
I made a code using iteration. 
However, large samples of big image make this calculation really slow.
So I want to get the other way like method using numpy array.

First I changed gray scale image into numpy array.
And I got the indices having certain value.
And I calculated thickness between these indices using numpy.where, max, min method.

```
import numpy as np

# this is a numpy array made of image file
im_np = np.array(
      [[255,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0],
       [255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]])

def area_seg (image_numpy):
    area = 0 
    num = np.where(image_numpy == 0 )[1]
    for i in range (min(num), max(num)):
        height = max(np.where(image_numpy[:,i]==0)[0]) - \
                 min(np.where(image_numpy[:,i]==0)[0])
        area += height
    return area

area_seg (im_np)
```

This gives me the answer I expect, but how can I do the same thing without using a for loop?

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: This runs correctly. But I want to know other way not using for loop?

Comment: I think that the slowest part in your code is array creation.

Comment: Two lines can't form an area. You should clarify how the area is defined.

Comment: To clarify the meaning of area, this is sum of thickness between two lines. If this is a covered by polygon, I found the solution to get the area.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Canny Edge Detection and follow by a Hough transform to extract lines from your image. And then, use simple math to calculate area between those lines.

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html